# How to set one property for multiple children element using tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I have a `contenteditable` div on my page and i want to every child ul and ol element to have a left padding in it using tailwind

```
<div class="[&_ol]:pl-4 [&_ul]:pl-4" contenteditable>
  <ol>
    <li>ordered list item</li>
  </ol>

  <ul>
    <li>ordered list item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

is it possible to unite selectors so i don't have to changed padding for every element in the future? something like `class="[&_ol,&_ul]:pl-4"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple selectors in arbitrary variants [is explicitly not supported](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/10655) but you could consider working around this restriction by using the [`:is()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="[&_:is(ol,ul)]:pl-4" contenteditable>
  <ol>
    <li>ordered list item</li>
  </ol>

  <ul>
    <li>ordered list item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```